# TSQL: How to ouput records even when where condition doesnt match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

I have a temp table with 3 columns "ID","Cost", "MaxCost"..below is my select statement which selects rows given particular ID..

```
        SELECT
            t.Cost 
            t.MaxCost
        FROM @temp t
        WHERE t.ID = @ID
```

How do i modify the above query so that even if given ID doesn't exists it still  output rows with Cost = 0 & MaxCost = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both the actual and the default record, and select the first one ordering by their weight.

```
select top (1)
  Cost,
  MaxCost
from (
  SELECT
    t.Cost 
    t.MaxCost,
    1 as takeme
  FROM @temp t
  WHERE t.ID = @ID

  union all

  select 0, 0, 0
) foo
order by
  foo.takeme desc
```

Comment: Your answer is correct based on my question..but i think its not going to work for what i'm trying to do..

Comment: @user3862378 How is this correct when the stated question is records - plural?

Comment: @Frisbee Because plural rows does not make sense in the context of this question and hence was ignored as a typo. [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364467/11683) arguably makes even less sense. What the OP actually [meant to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34364484/11683).

Comment: @GSerg  Rows was three typos?  It was a simple question.  There is no purpose to attacking an answer that takes a question as written.  And if it is just one ID my answer still works and is less lines than yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (cost int); 
insert into @table values (2), (2), (3);

declare @findCost int = 1; 

select * from @table where cost = @findCost
union all
select 0 as cost from @table where cost = @findCost having count(*) = 0;

set @findCost = 2;

select * from @table where cost = @findCost
union all
select 0 as cost from @table where cost = @findCost having count(*) = 0;
```